# Android call broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create Call broadcast receiver.I have successfully created  broadcast receiver service and also added manifest file.
My program is working perfect,but in emulator I can call when use only DDMS Incoming number (like this)
[image]

now i want to run my app in divice.i want editext's toString would be incoming number.what's all

How can I solve it?
Below is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    IncomingCall.class);
            sendBroadcast(in);

        }
    });

}



public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

    tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {


        Log.d("MyPhoneListener", state + "   incoming no:" + incomingNumber);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

add String number=intent.getExtras().getString("incoming_number"); in your on receive ,here number is the number that you will receive